# Is the number of non-EU/EEA students seeking PhD in the UK declining?

Tags: united-kingdom

I am just curious.

Coz, after all of those tuition fee hike, job visa ban, and so on is the UK still a popular destination to do a "**3-year PhD**"?

Is the number of non-EU/EEA students seeking PhD in the UK declining?

Comment: There's no job visa ban in the UK.

Comment: @AlexeyB., yes there is.....Degree holders are bound to get out of the country as soon as they complete their education.

Comment: Not if you find a job or apply for a doctorate extension scheme.

Comment: @AlexeyB., what happens after PhD and Postdoctoral?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @AlexeyB., I mean, Suppose, somebody completes a PhD and a postdoctoral in then UK. That means, all his academic options are used up. Can he still do job in the UK?

Comment: There's no such things as using up the academic options. You can get multiple postdoc (RA in UK terms) appointments and maybe a lectureship eventually. It is true that the competition for academic positions is high, and the rules of Tier 2 (work) visas are complicated, but there's no ban.